# reCaptcha любого сайта

Tags: html, delphi, recaptcha, tchromium

Имеется

```
data-sitekey="6LeryxQUAAAAADCsy4AFQwaBdL3bGRuGc9VeoC8H"
```

и сам Host сайта на котором расположена рекапча.

Как вывести в webbrowser или в tchromium, не загружая больше ничего, кроме самой рекапчи ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeryxQUAAAAADCsy4AFQwaBdL3bGRuGc9VeoC8H"></div>
```

Работающий [пример](http://test.kagg.eu/so/625799.html). В примере указан публичный ключ моего домена, выводится нормально. С ключом вашего домена из вопроса - показывает ошибку, ясное дело, потому что мой домен не соответствует вашему ключу.

Comment: Спасибо за код. Но вот вопрос, как открыть его на чужом домене, для меня остался открытым. Пробую подменить внутренний хтмл, ничего не происходит... `AssignFile(f, 'kis.txt');
  Reset(f);
  Readln(f, kis);
  CloseFile(f);

  DocS := (form1.webbrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument2).all as IHTMLElementCollection;
  for ib := 0 to DocS.Length - 1 do
  begin
    elem := DocS.item(ib, 0) as IHTMLElement;
    if elem.tagName = 'html' then
      elem.innerHTML:=kis;
  end;`

Comment: Это зачем такие упражнения? Капчу решили поломать?)

Comment: Пишу свой клиент для сайтов, они довольно тяжелые и загружать всё нет смысла. Пытаюсь оставить только рекапчу.

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос "как вывести капчу" устроил,  то его можно отметить как принятый.

Comment: Эх, если бы вопрос был бы решён... Как сделать фрейм рекапчи на своём сайте это мне известно. А вот как загрузить фрейм рекапчи с чужим доменом? 
 Знаю что это возможно.

Comment: ну, вопрос так не стоял. Слово "чужой" в вопросе отсутствует. Кроме того, вывести рабочую рекапчу для чужого домена на свой сайт невозможно, какие бы сказки не приходилось слышать на этот счет. Не надо считать Google дурнее паровоза. Их скрипт проверяет публичный ключ и сравнивает с адресом домена, на котором форма запущена.

Comment: ТОгда каким образом это делают антигейт и рукапча.ру ? )

Comment: Я так и понял с самого начала, что интересует вопрос взлома капчи. Здесь неподходящее место для этого. С такими вопросами следует обращаться на mail.ru.

Comment: Возьми сниффер, проанализируй пакеты. Потом возьми примитивный TCP и повтори тоже самое. Там проблемы (95%) в полях заголовка (скорее всего Referer). Я не знаю, может поля заголовка можно поменять и в webbrowser (или в tchromium). Как вариант там может быть AJAX, сниффер это покажет.

Comment: Ох, ну откуда вас тут столько. Мы на серьезном ресурсе для программистов вроде. Вы про шифрование по открытым ключам слышали что-нибудь? Не зная секретного ключа домена, нихрена вы там не поймете в этих пакетах. А вишенка на торте - это предложение перехватывать и подменять https-пакеты. Ну да, MITM на Google - удачи, ребята.

Comment: А что, если поднять локальный сервер с таким же названием домена?